# Why does a Wadler-Leijen pretty printer use Union instead of Group?

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

[Hughes-style](http://belle.sourceforge.net/doc/hughes95design.pdf) pretty-printing combinators use a `Union` primitive for describing sets of differing layouts, but [Wadler](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/prettier/prettier.pdf) replaced `Union` with `Group`, which tries to layout its argument on one line and then breaks lines if it can’t. Yet the latest [Wadler-Leijen](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.2.0.1/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html) combinators make `Union` primitive, and define `group d` as `Union (flatten d) d`. What are the trade-offs between the two representations, and why do Wadler-Leijen pretty printers use `Union`?

Answer (score 1):

Wadler's algorithm was first implemented in Haskell, which is lazily evaluated.

A 'Group' is evaluated as a choice of 2 options - one with the grouped text all on one line, and one with it on multiple lines. This is expressed as a 'Union' of these two options. A group is turned into a union, but the 2 options are only calculated lazily due to being implemented in Haskell.

By contrast, see this implementation in Stanard ML which is strictly evaluated.

https://github.com/kfl/wpp/blob/master/Wpp.sml

The author there has made 'Group' a primitive and not 'Union'. This is so that the 2 options are only computed on demand, when evaluating how to layout a group.

This isn't needed in the Haskell implementation. Also note that the Haskell library has a 'softline' function, which uses union. The SML doesn't, presumably since softline is not expressed so well by a group. The SML implementation could have taken a different path, by putting the choices under a union behind a thunk '() -> ...', to make them lazier, for example.

===

I just checked the implemenation of softline and it is 'group Line', so I was wrong about group not being the way to implement softline.

Still I think the answer is that union is a general choice of two layouts, but group is a specific choice between a single line or multi-line layout and other choices ought to be possible and can be handled by the layout algorithm.

Comment: That sort of makes sense, but as you point out, why not make Union lazy?

Comment: I guess in that SML implementation the author had no intention of doing any kind of union other than as a group - maybe a good insight.

Comment: I ported it to Elm, and I currently have a non-lazy Union. Now considering whether I should replace with Group or make the Union lazy. I guess I will go with Group until such time as I feel the need to implement some other kind of union.